# Must every convex compact set have extreme points?

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis, convex-geometry, polytopes, convex-hulls

I am reading a paper and there is such description as title. Why?

I have an example:  $(0,1)$. This is a convex set but not closed, so I cannot find an extreme point. However if convex and compact,

I read some related problems:

1. [Exposed point of a compact convex set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1119943/exposed-point-of-a-compact-convex-set)
   There must be at least one exposed point. But an extreme point is not necessary equal to an exposed point.
2. [Convex hull of extreme points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/282036/convex-hull-of-extreme-points)
   A convex hull $P$ of finite points. Then $P$ is the convex hull of its extreme points.

It seems there is a requirement "finite points" to guarantee the topic?

Comment: Duplicate? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1384579/prove-that-the-set-of-extreme-points-of-a-compact-convex-set-is-not-empty

Comment: Yes, that is what I want.

Comment: What is the setting here, are we talking about Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$ or a normed space, or a locally convex topological space?

Comment: Actually the paper is about positive semidefinite matrices with unity trace and rank one, which form extreme points

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a finite dimensional space (which is the case here, according to [a comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1847169/convex-compact-set-must-have-extreme-points#comment3781221_1847169)), the existence of an extreme point of a compact convex set  $K$ is easy to prove. Take any point $x\in K$ at which the norm $\|x\|$ is maximized. If there is $y\ne 0$ such that $x\pm y \in K$, then 
$$
2\|x\|^2 \ge \|x+y\|^2 + \|x-y\|^2 =  2\|x\|^2+2\|y\|^2> 2\|x\|^2
$$
 a contradiction.

Comment: What is this contradicting? That $x$ is not and extreme point? How do I know there is a $y$ such that $x \pm y \in K$?