# Is there a simple proof that every compact convex $K\subset \Bbb R^n$ has at least one extreme point?

Tags: convex-analysis, compactness, normed-spaces, locally-convex-spaces, convex-hulls

Can someone give me a simple proof that every compact convex $K\subset \Bbb R^n$  has at least one extreme point?

I'd found this one but couln't understand it: [Convex compact set must have extreme points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1847169/convex-compact-set-must-have-extreme-points)

Thanks!

Comment: @CaveJohnson So how could you define "extreme point" in a non-convex set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a sphere $S $ of radius $r$ where $K$ is inscribed in $S$.

Here inscribed implies that $K$ is in $r$-ball $B$ with a boundary
$S$ and there is a point $x\in K$ s.t. $x$ is in $S$.

Then $x$ is an extreme point of $K$. If not, there is $p,\ q\neq p
\in K$ s.t. $x$ is an interior point of a segment $[pq]$.

Note that $B$ can not contain a segment $[pq]$ so that $[pq]$ is not
in $K$. It is a contradiction.

Comment: How do you know that $K$ can be inscribed in a sphere?

Answer (score 6):

Take a point of $K$ that maximizes Euclidean distance from the origin.  This exists since a continuous function on a compact set attains its supremum, and it is easily seen to be an extreme point (you may want to use the [Parallelogram Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law) for this).